# How to add data into an useState variable

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, use-state

I am a newbie to React.js and Firestore.
I have been struggling with adding data fetched from Firestore through useEffect and getDocs() into an useState variable.

I wanna fetch all quizzes from Firestore in useEffect.

```js
// I define quizzes like this
  const [quizzes, setQuizzes] = useState([]);
// After that, call useEffect. 
  useEffect(() => {
    const collectionRef = collection(db, 'quizzes');
    const getQuizzes = async () => {
      const snapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef)
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, "=> ", doc.data());
        setQuizzes([...quizzes, doc.data()]);
      })
    }
    getQuizzes();

  }, []);
```

I thought this code `setQuizzes([...quizzes, doc.data()]);` would add each quiz to the end of the current quizzes list.

However, what happened here is that the variable contains only one quz. I guess the last quiz out of all.

Thanks for your valuable time in advance^^

Answer (score 0):

Modifying state is an asynchronous operation, so each call to `setQuizzes` in your loop is essentially replacing the previous call(s).

You also only need one call:

```
const snapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef)
setQuizes(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
```